# What's the difference between the tag "android-apps" and the tag "android"?

Tags: discussion, tags

So pretty much everything is in the title: What's the difference between the tag "android-apps" and the tag "android"?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see the tag was created by [this **closed** question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4196/107).

To me android-apps is just a stupid tag - basically to my mind if that was a good tag we should have Windows-Software and OSX-software etc.. which is just *YUCK*

Android is an operating system, if you tag a question with [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) then running on Android is a requirement.

Comment: And as such I'm editing to remove the tag and replace with [tag:android] where applicable - some of the six questions with that tag had *both*

Comment: right oh that tag will be trashed next system refresh